# jQuery check if one of the inputs with same class is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having two elements with same classname and I am doing `$(".text-input")` to select all of them. In the on input callback,

```
$(".text-input").on("input", function (event) {
console.log(is any of those not empty?);
})
```

in of any one of these, I want to know if at least one of the input boxes are not empty. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you shoulld always `.trim()` the content before testing.
You don't want whitespaces to account for a valid input value:

```js
$(".text-input").on("input", function() {
   const is_empty = !this.value.trim();
   if (is_empty) console.log("field is empty");
   $(this).toggleClass("is-empty", is_empty);
});
```

```css
/* bool helpers */
.is-empty {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input">
<input type="text" class="text-input">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To answer your second question:

> *"I want to know **if at least one of the input boxes are not empty**. How do I do this?"*

- Use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
    // Return true if at least one input has value
    const atLeastOneNotEmpty = (elements) => {
      return [...elements].some(el => el.value.trim());
    }
```

Example code

```js
const $inp = $(".text-input");

const validateEmpty = () => {
  $inp.each((i, el) => {
     const is_empty = !el.value.trim();
     if (is_empty) console.log(`field ${el.name} is empty`);
     el.classList.toggle("is-empty", is_empty);
  }); 
};

// Return true if at least one input has value
const atLeastOneNotEmpty = (ELs) => [...ELs].some(el => el.value.trim());

$inp.on('input', validateEmpty);

$("#test").on("click", () => {
  console.log(atLeastOneNotEmpty(jQuery.makeArray($inp)))
});
```

```css
/* bool helpers */
.is-empty {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-input" name="a"><br>
<input type="text" class="text-input" name="b" value="foo"><br>
<input type="text" class="text-input" name="c"><br>
<button id="test" type="button">TEST one has value</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"[...]I want to know if at least one of the input boxes are not empty."* It's the same as 
Francesco Vallone's answer - in that it is not solving OPs issue.

Comment: @Lapskaus I was adding more to this answer

Comment: Just a heads up that `some` is a misnomer as it actually means `any` - "some" would mean ">1" but it's ">=1" - 1 is never "some".  (not related to the answer just voicing).

Comment: You misunderstand my comment `.some()` is the correct thing to use here - "some" is incorrectly named within javascript

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for the noise, just interested in how would you prefer that method to be named? `one`? `atLeastOne`? `hasOne`? ... seems `some` is a fair choice, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the content of all `text-input` elements in with the `each()` method. With `not(this)` you can exclude the currently typed into textbox.

```js
$('.text-input').on('input change', function() {
    // check all elements with the 'text-input class', but exclude the one currrently typed into
    $('.text-input').not(this).each(function(){
    // if there is content in one of the others, then display a message in console
    if($(this).val().trim().length > 0) {
        // one of the inputs already has something in it
      console.log('Something is filled in another box');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is use `filter()` to create a collection of the ones that have values and then compare length of that collection to length of all the inputs

```js
const $inputs = $('.text-input').on('input', function() {

  const $filled = $inputs.filter((_, el) => !!el.value.trim());

  console.clear();

  if ( $filled.length < $inputs.length ) {
    console.log('At least one is empty')
  } else {
    console.log('No empties')
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
<input type="text" class="text-input" />
```

Comment: At least one. Therefore `.some()` would be preferred for a large collection and its early-return benefits. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512515/383904) - So early exit with a `Boolean` instead of creating in-memory large filtered collections of elements.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan A few form inputs is hardly a large collection

Answer (score -2):

You can just check if the length of the value of each input is equal to 0. If it is then do whatever you want.
Here is the code.

```
$(".text-input").on("input", function (event) {
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        console.log("is any of those not empty?");
    }
});
```

Comment: But that will only check the input that is currently typed into. What you are doing is basically checking if you deleted all content from that one input.

Comment: I can't see how this even remotely solves OPs issue of "*at least **one** of the input boxes are not empty*" as if the one being entered into is not empty but the other one **is empty** (as per requirement) this will no hit the console.log